# how do I use mod_rewrite to re-use old url param value in new redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to do a 301 redirect from

oldpage.php?arg1=123&arg2=abc

to

newpage.php?arg3=abc

I'm pretty mediocre at htaccess rules but seems this should be fairly straightforward.

Do I have to first rewrite the old url to folder structure so I can extract the value and then do another rewrite using that?  Or...?

I can't figure out how to re-use arg2 value as the arg3 value in the redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule to pick desired value from `QUERY_STRING`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)arg2=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldpage\.php$ /newpage.php?arg3=%1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed.